# Store a Jmeter JSR223 script in a variable

Tags: groovy, automation, scripting, jmeter

I have a Jmeter script with many HTTP Requests, each with a JSR223 preprocessor. Most of the preprocessors have common code and I want to reference that code from one place, not necessarily functions but a large piece of code that is duplicated in all preprocessors. I've experimented with a few things and I came across in the Jmeter documentation the mention of storing a script in a JSR223 Sampler and then in a variable and then referencing the variable with ${__groovy(${RANDOM_NAME})}.

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#developing_scripts

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#how

I cannot find any examples of this working in a real script. I understand most of this but I am not sure how "it can be stored as a variable on the Test Plan". I have the code in a JSR223 sample in a thread group that is called before all others but am not sure how to store it as a variable. Can someone please show me a working example of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of options regarding how you can store the script into a variable.

- The easiest and the most straightforward is using [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables)

  [image]
- If you're targeting to use [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) there is a [special property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#groovy): *groovy.utilities* where you can specify the path to the file holding the "common" code
- And finally you can [compile your "common" code into a .jar file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-reuse-your-jmeter-code-with-jar-files-and-save-time) and it will be available to any scripting elements, moreover it will work faster.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It didn't occur to me to put the entire text into the variable but this does seem to work. I am facing other issues with this but as a concept, it is working as you describe.

Answer (score 1):

I think a more suitable solution is to use same [Script File](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) in JSR223 sampler

> Script File

> Name of a file to be used as a JSR223 script, if a relative file path is used, then it will be relative to directory referenced by "user.dir" System property

But you can save script as JMeter property, for example in user.properties

```
  MyScript=[script]
```

And define in Test plan a variable with value `${__P(MyScript)}`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Using a variable is somewhat working but there are some issues with it so I will give this idea a try and see how it works.